# How do I change content from my MainWindow when I click a button from inside my UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I just started learning MVVM and I want to know what the best practice would be when I want to change content from my MainWindow when I click a button from inside my UserControl.

This is the UserControl which contains the buttons that I will be clicking. When I click on the IconButtons this produces, I want to be able to change the MainGrid to a Grid containing the information from my IconModel.

For clarification, I would like the Grid to show the Icon's Name, Description, Username, Password, and have a button that would open up either a program or a website using Path. The Icon class is inside IconModel.cs which is posted below.

IconView.xaml

```xml
    <UserControl x:Class="ProgramManager.Views.IconView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProgramManager"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:ProgramManager.ViewModel"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModel:IconViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path = Icons}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Name="IconButton" Style="{StaticResource IconButtonStyle}" Content="{Binding Path = Initial, Mode = OneWay}" Click="Button_Click">
                        <Button.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip Content="{Binding Path = Name, Mode = TwoWay}"/>
                        </Button.ToolTip>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

MainWindow.xaml

```xml
    <Window x:Class="ProgramManager.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProgramManager"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:ProgramManager.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Name="MainGrid" Grid.Column="1">

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

For reference, here are my IconModel and IconViewModel classes.

IconModel.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ProgramManager.Model
{

    public class IconModel { }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Icons", IsNullable = true, DataType = "string")]
    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(ProgramIcon))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(WebsiteIcon))]
    public class Icon : IComparable<Icon>, IComparer<Icon>, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string name;
        private string description;
        private string path;
        private string username;
        private string password;

        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                if (name != value)
                {
                    name = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
                }
            }
        }

        [XmlElement("Description")]
        public string Description
        {
            get { return description; }
            set
            {
                if (description != value)
                {
                    description = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Description");
                }
            }
        }

        [XmlElement("Path")]
        public string Path
        {
            get { return path; }
            set
            {
                if (path != value)
                {
                    path = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Path");
                }
            }
        }

        [XmlElement("Username")]
        public string Username
        {
            get { return username; }
            set
            {
                if (username != value)
                {
                    username = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Username");
                }
            }
        }

        [XmlElement("Password")]
        public string Password
        {
            get { return password; }
            set
            {
                if (password != value)
                {
                    password = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Password");
                }
            }
        }

        public string Initial {
            get
            {
                return this.Name.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }

        public int Compare(Icon x, Icon y)
        {
            return (x.Equals(null) || y.Equals(null)) ? 0 : x.CompareTo(y);
        }

        public int CompareTo(Icon other)
        {
            return string.Compare(this.Name, other.Name);
        }
    }

    public class ProgramIcon : Icon { }
    public class WebsiteIcon : Icon { }
}
```

IconViewModel.cs

```cs
using ProgramManager.Helpers;
using ProgramManager.Model;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;

namespace ProgramManager.ViewModel
{
    public class IconViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private static readonly List<Icon> iconsList;
        private ObservableCollection<Icon> icons;
        public ObservableCollection<Icon> Icons
        {
            get { return icons; }
            set
            {
                if (icons != value)
                {
                    icons = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Icons");
                }
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }

        public IconViewModel()
        {
            LoadIcons();
        }

        static IconViewModel()
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(Constants.ResourcesDirectory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Constants.ResourcesDirectory);
            }

            iconsList = XmlDataStorage.GetList<Icon>(Constants.IconsFilePath);
        }

        public void LoadIcons()
        {
            ObservableCollection<Icon> icons = new ObservableCollection<Icon>();

            foreach(var icon in iconsList)
            {
                icons.Add(icon);
            }

            Icons = icons;
        }

        public void AddIcon(Icon icon)
        {
            iconsList.Add(icon);
            iconsList.Sort();

            XmlDataStorage.SaveToXml(Constants.IconsFilePath, iconsList);

            LoadIcons();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried accessing the IconButton in MainWindow from the IconView.xaml, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can access the main window like `Application.Current.MainWindow`.
2. For MVVM solution  you can do somethig like (Take the idea, I didn't compiled this):

inside MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Label DataContext="{IconViewModel }" Content={Binding YourProperty}/>
```

I mean you can set the data context of the label to be the IconViewModel and the to bind the property from IconViewModel class.

3. third option is to create an event inside IconViewModel and when you click the button to invoke the event, and the mainwindow will subscribe to this event.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you change the IconView.xaml to a ContentTemplate?And the IconButton Binding a dependency property.So that you can operate the IconButton  anywhere.Iclude the MainWindow.